# How to animate selected icon size change in NavigationBar similar to BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm working with Flutter. When I change the icon using the NavigationBar I want the selected icon to have a larger size, but make this change animated, similar to how it happens in the BottonNavigationBar, but the NavigationBar version I have not been able to achieve this animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AnimatedScale(
  scale: factor,
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  child: NavigationDestination(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.home, // your icon
    ),
    label: '',
  ),
)
```

Just update the `factor` using setState or any state management

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AnimatedContainer**
here is an example

```
AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          width: isSelected ? 2.0 : 0.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child: Icon(
      icons[index],
      size: isSelected ? selectedIconSize : unselectedIconSize,
      color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
    ),
```

Comment: You can try to use Animatable, calculate the value after the animation through LaunchEffect, and finally set the value to the icon of BottomNavigationItem

Answer (score 0):

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: model.currentIndex,
          enableFeedback: true,
          landscapeLayout: BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.centered,
          elevation: 0,
          onTap: model.setIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'Hem',
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: CustomeColors.grey,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                size: 25.0,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This the Material 2 version, i'm using NavigationBar, the Material 3 bottom navigation bar

Comment: is it a diffrent widget youre using because it works for me